# symfony 3.4 unrecognized option in config

Tags: php, symfony, yaml, symfony4, symfony-3.4

Can you help me to resolve this problem? I am trying to the **composer update**

> ```
> Unrecognized option "environment" under "test_sq.fallback"
> ```

config_dev.yml

```
 test_sq:
   fallback:
     environment: dev
```

Comment: Don't upgrade the `test_sq` bundle then. Use specific version constraint inside `composer.json`. You used `dev-master` probably. Can't tell since you didn't post your `composer.json` file.

Comment: What is `test_sq`? is it a bundle?

Comment: Yes. it is bundle.